# How likely will my code generate Duplicate IDs?

Tags: php, sql, random

Good day all. As the question states. How likely is the code below to generate duplicate IDs? The reason I would like to know this is to decide whether I should include a check against the whole database to search for duplicates and re-generate a new ID if there is. Let me know if any extra information is required. Also alternatives are greatly welcome. Thanks~

```
$query = "SELECT 'ID' FROM world_highscore";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: '. mysql_error());

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

//set of characters to be used in the ID.
$rand_charset = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", 
            "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");

//the seed is the current number of entries in the table + 1.
$seed = $num_results + 1;

//function to generate and return an ID
function randomizeID($seed, $rand_charset){
    $rand_id = array("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0");

    for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
        mt_srand($seed);
        $rand_id[$i] = $rand_charset[mt_rand(0, 35)];

        //not really sure if this is really required but the seed is incremented by one for each 
        //iteration to hopefully introduce more randomization.
        $seed++;    
    }
    return implode($rand_id);                       
}
```

Comment: 35 characters in the alphabet, 8 characters long. Isn't that `8 ^ 35`? (And that's not taking into account the `srand`.) So 4.0564819e+31 unique strings?

Comment: Thus hurts. It really does. Don't re-seed a PRNG unless you know what you're doing (which you don't, as a general rule). If you want collision-resistance, just use a GUID.

Comment: thx for the GUID recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Alternative,

```
$id = md5(time().rand(1, 999999));
```

Comment: yea but it's a solution that will never generate duplicate ids... Well never being not in his lifetime, but not absolutely never. That is not possible... So his answer is not wrong.. it is, as he said, a simple alternative

Comment: Yeah, it's not the answer, I just shared my thought with more maintainable code... If it's me, I will further check it against existing IDs in the database, but for generating an ID I think it's more faster (both in terms of performance and lines of code).